# Un ajout pour souligner qu’il y a des façons contraires pour s’exprimer

Tags: expressions

J’aimerais trouver une petite phrase spécifique en français. On l'emploie quand quelqu’un qui parle se rend compte qu’il peut dire le contraire de ce qu’il avait dit avant pour s’exprimer. Mon propos parait fumeux, donc je donne des exemples.

Des cambrioleurs se glissent dans une maison et emmènent des choses de grande valeur. Ils sont vus et donc ils se dépêchent de s’éloigner de la maison. Alors ils vont à la gare la plus proche pour s'échapper. Mais les employés sont en grève, ce qui retardent la fuite des cambrioleurs. Les gendarmes peuvent alors  arrêter les malfaiteurs à la gare.
Si quelqu’un a vent d’un tel événement il pourrait dire : « Le propriétaire de la maison a eu de la chance qu’on ait mal servi. Ou bien servi. *Tout dépend du point de vue.* »

Si je dis à quelqu’un que mon père est venu chez moi en pleine nuit j’aurai pareillement du mal à juger s’il vient tôt ou tard, donc je dirai : «  Il est venu tôt. Ou peut-être tard, *ça dépend.* »

Reconnaissez quelque chose que l’on utilise en français ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il me semble qu'on entend le plus souvent dans ce cas :

> [*C'est une*] *Question de point de vue*...

(La partie entre crochets, facultative, rend l'expression légèrement plus soutenue.)

Mais il y a en effet des variantes possibles, dont celles citées par cl-r. On pourrait éventuellement ajouter cette autre phrase nominale :

> *Selon comme on l'entend...*

Answer (score 2):

Les premières expressions qui viennent à l'esprit :

> « C'est vous qui voyez ! », expression tirée d'un célèbre sketch du duo Chevallier et Laspalès qui parle lui aussi de trains et des problèmes de choix d'horaire
>   .
>
> « C'est à vous de voir. »
>
> « C'est selon. »

Comment: La première expression est « C'est vous qui voyez ! », pas « C'est à vous de voir ».    http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C'est_vous_qui_voyez_!

Comment: @jlliagre Merci - Correction effectuée - Comme quoi, ce qui vient en premier à l'esprit doit être vérifié!